# Checkinstall not found though already installed (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, checkinstall

I am trying to install Cuneiform following a usual procedure (downloading archive, unpacking, using make etc). One of the steps in building it is `sudo checkinstall`. When I run this in the terminal, I get the following error:

> sudo: ckeckinstall: command not found

I am new to Ubuntu, and not a programmer, so this may be a very simple question. What I have learned so far is that I can install software through `sudo apt-get install [name]`. When I do this, I get a message that `checkinstall` is already installed. Also, looking it up in the Software Centre I saw a green tick next to it (which means that it is installed). So why do I get the message that the command is not found and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the binary file of checkinstall is in `/usr/bin/checkinstall`

Try to check where is the executables with the command:
`whereis [name]` and then run it!

Comment: Actually, I tried using `sudo checkinstall` again on a different day, and it all worked perfectly well. It's inexplicable to me.